# Preventing Thread.sleep from blacking out screen

Tags: android

I want to insert a pause in my create after loading the layout before I start a video.

The layout loads an image which I want to display for 3 seconds before I start a video.

This is what I've tried (this code is in the `onCreate` method)

```
      setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
      try {
          Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch ...
           ...
      }
      startVideo();
```

The problem is that calling `Thread.sleep` blacks the display and then the video starts.

How can I make the screen not go black?

Comment: Do not run Thread.sleep() in the UI thread. Android will kill your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're blocking the UIThread thats what is causing it to go blank...
Replace your `try {...}` block with the following:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startVideo();
        }
    }, 3000);
```

And consider putting that in the `onStart` or `onResume`...

You should also read [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) to get an idea of what runs where and where you can block and where you cannot...