# getting blackscreen between activities using a timer

Tags: android

i have read multiple links and tried various things yet i can not get the black screen to dissapear any suggestions here is my manifest the activity that is calling the next activity and xmls,code

its basically a splash screen that after 5 seconds it opens another activity it was working two days ago and last night i fixed a logical error then this started tried reverting it to the way it was before i edited it and yet still a black screen after the splash has been displayed.

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.audiovolumecontrol"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.audiovolumecontrol.Options"
        android:label="@string/options_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="VolumeControlMAIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".com.example.audiovolumecontrol.VolumeControlMAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

splash xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_main2"
android:orientation="vertical" 

>

</LinearLayout>
```

Splash Code

```
package com.example.audiovolumecontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splash extends Activity 
{


     private static int LOGO_TIME_OUT = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


}

@Override
protected void onStart() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent openSTART = new Intent                               
                            (Splash.this,VolumeControlMAIN.class);
                startActivity(openSTART); 
            }
        }, LOGO_TIME_OUT );






}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

help would be appreciated

I have tried multiple suggestions and noneof them worked from changing the theme to the on start methods and changing variables .... this program worked previously and now once my splash has shown and the time is up i just get a black screen

Comment: Found similar post with a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511696/preventing-thread-sleep-from-blacking-out-screen

Comment: Thanks i think i understand il give it a try

Comment: I tried it yet i am still getting this black screen after my splash has shown any idea what i  can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-->

```
        private static int LOGO_TIME_OUT = 3000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,VolumeControlMAIN.class);
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
    }, LOGO_TIME_OUT);
```

}

Hope it helps u..:)

Comment: unfortunatly i am still stuck with a black screen is it possible that there a problem with my manifest?

Comment: oh... :( actually i created a project in my local and tried ..its working for me...

Comment: in your local? local class?

Comment: you have lost me bud i have bo idea what a local machine is

Comment: ok is there any way or thing to try to fix my blank screen as my project if finished but this final test has caused this problem i really need to get it done and ive tried multiple things

Comment: the black screen is after my splash has been displayed so it must be on the start activity part or something

Comment: i solved the problem it is when you pass a value from a method to another method causing this problem so a method that accepts a variable then works on it and returns it to another method then does seperate calculations in that method .... dont ask me why but that is what i found was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Follow these 2 steps: (If you are using android version ICS)

1. Just go to settings / Developer Options / Window Animation Scale and turn it off.
2. Likewise, Just go to settings / Developer Options / the transition animation scale and turn it off!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the `onCreate` of your `VolumeControlMAIN` class? If you are doing a lot of work on `onCreate` of `VolumeControlMAIN` then the layout won't appear till all the work is done.